# What JVM language + web framework do you use with Google Appengine Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Looking for the least bumpy (and most productive ) ride for a web 2.0 idea...

Groovy/Grails, Scala/Lift, Groovy/Gaelyk, OR....

Please share your experience.

Comment: As currently phrased, this question has no correct answer, and should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of using a predominantly google stack:

- eclipse ide with google plugins
- gwt + [dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) + [presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/) + [gin](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) + [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) on the back end

I first saw this stack as [appleguice](http://code.google.com/p/appleguice/),
I've also seen it used by [hupa](http://james.apache.org/hupa/index.html)

I haven't used it yet, so I can't vouch for it being tried and tested,
but you should have a look at the [video](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) linked from the dispatch and presenter.

Answer (score 1):

I vote JRuby + Rails3

Comment: is this based on personal experience on appengine?  I thought JRuby was having problems with poor response times due to framework startup time.

Comment: Is not based on personal experience, but i believe it to be a good choice, Rails3 is a lot faster and JRuby improved a lot since 1.3.1 (current 1.4.0) and 1.5.0 release is iminent. Startup times is irelevant (starts once then serves requests). Runtime is fast-enough and this is also made irrelevant by caching, mostly.

Comment: startup time is very relevant on app engine.  apps often get shutdown and then restarted from scratch, as part of the auto scaling nature of the platform.  Every time a new instance is started, some user is getting annoyed that they have to wait 10 seconds (or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying with Spring MVC + Groovy. It's just a REST application (without any html views, just a JSON and XML), and all is ok. 
But data access layer requires too much work :( My previous gae app was made using python+django, and it was more better.

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) 6.7 IDE with [Google App Engine plugin](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/google-app-engine-plugin-for-netbeans-6-7/) and [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/).